# How to do url parameterization from csv in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Parameterization of server name or IP  from csv in jmeter 
Eg:www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.bing.com

How to Parameterise these values in a single script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any other parameterization

Given your CSV file looks like:

```
google.com
bing.com
yahoo.com
```

Create your test plan as follows:

- Thread Group (threads: 1, loops: 3)

  - CSV Data Set Config (Filename: path to your csv file, Variable names: anything meaningful, i.e. `server`)
  - HTTP Request: (Server Name or IP: `${server}`

[image: CSV Data Set Config]

[image: HTTP Request]

You can also optionally add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to visualise request and response details.

[image: View Results Tree]

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config) for detailed walkthrough and few more tips and tricks

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong. Do you want to randomly choose which IP would JMeter use?

You can create values like host1 host2 host3, and then simply add ${host${__Random(1,3,)}}
Unless you have a ton of different hosts, then my approach is sloppy :)